# standard babel presets requirements

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

In order to setup webpack + babel + react, I was told to include following in `.babelrc`:

```
"presets": ["latest", "stage-0", "react"]
```

I want to understand: why should I use babel presets, what do they allow me to do (apart from babel itself)? That's one question. Hope that's not opinion-based (in terms of stackoverflow), it's about how babel works.

As far as I read in the [docs, `preset-latest`](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-latest/) combines `preset-es2015` + `preset-es2016` + `preset-es2017`. As far as I understand, these are officially accepted features of upcoming ES versions and latest is a shorthand for choosing not only ES2015, but all future versions at one shot. The specs won't change, so it's stable enough to use in production.

But how about `stage-0`, `stage-1`, `stage-2`, `stage-3` - do they represent features that are still unofficial proposals of upcoming ECMAScript versions or does that stand for something else? [Babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/) is not clear about that. That's second question.

And finally, what is the difference between a *plugin* and a *preset*?

Comment: The docs seem to cover most of your questions: *"Now, out of the box Babel doesn’t do anything. It basically acts like `const babel = code => code;` by parsing the code and then generating the same code back out again. You will need to add some plugins for Babel to do anything (they affect the 2nd stage, transformation). **Presets** Don’t want to assemble your own set of plugins? No problem! Presets are sharable `.babelrc` configs or simply an array of babel plugins. Each yearly preset only compiles what was ratified in that year. Use preset-latest to transform all yearly presets."*...

Comment: ... *"**Stage-X (Experimental Presets)** Any transforms in stage-x presets are changes to the language that haven’t been approved to be part of a release of Javascript (such as ES6/ES2015)."* https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/

Comment: Related: [what's the difference between babel-preset-stage-0, babel-preset-stage-1 etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37251552/whats-the-difference-between-babel-preset-stage-0-babel-preset-stage-1-etc)

Answer (score 6):

> ...why should I use babel presets, what do they allow me to do...

A Babel preset conveniently defines a group of Babel plugins so that you don't have to explicitly declare you want to use each of them under `"plugins"` in your `.babelrc` (or wherever you declare your config).

Take a look at the source code of the `es2016` preset and you'll see what I mean... it simply exports an array of plugins: https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-es2016/src/index.js

> ...(apart from babel itself)?

Babel itself is an *interface* for its plugins. It utilises a sibling program, [`babylon`](https://github.com/babel/babylon), a fork of [`acorn`](https://github.com/ternjs/acorn), that provides plugins a particular way of parsing, inspecting, and then manipulating the source code of your program, in order to add the features you want according to the plugins you use.

> And finally, what is the difference between a plugin and a preset?

As discussed, a preset itself does not contain features, rather a list of plugins. Together these typically represent some related group of functionality. For example, the `stage-0` preset will contain all plugins that implement features of proposals which are at stage zero of the [process of submission](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/) defined by TC39, ECMAScript's "governing body".

You might have noticed that a preset is a JavaScript file instead of JSON. This is because the list of plugins that a preset defines can be derived from a configuration. Take a look at the `env` preset, for example: https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env/blob/master/src/index.js

> But how about stage-0, stage-1, stage-2, stage-3 - do they represent features that are still unofficial proposals of upcoming ECMAScript versions or does that stand for something else?

There are no "official" proposals. A proposal can be submitted by anyone. But if what you mean by official is whether the proposal is being seriously considered, that is determined by 1) what stage it is at in the process and 2) general consideration by the community of its worth as a new feature. However you should always take proposals with a pinch of salt in terms of whether they will be accepted, even at the last stage, as we have experienced with `Object#observe`, which was [dropped at the very last minute](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/an-update-on-object-observe).

Answer (score 1):

I also didn't understand why `"modules": false` and why there is an "env" setting and that `env` has its own preset configuration.

Finally, I found this article [What's in our .babelrc?](https://sebastiandedeyne.com/posts/2017/whats-in-our-babelrc) explains it well, e.g

> Secondly, we set modules to false to ensure that import statements are
>   left as is (opposed to transpiling them to require). We're doing this
>   to give Webpack the ability to statically analyze our code to produce
>   more efficient bundles.
>
> Lastly, we have an environment specific override for Jest, our testing
>   framework of choice. Since Jest is run in node, we need to transpile
>   our imports to requires, and target whatever node runtime we're
>   currently working in.