# My Syntax is correct, but I am still getting the error

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am attempting to render my React application on my server, but in my routes.js file I am coming across an error which I cannot seem to resolve.The error I am getting is

```
Unterminated JSX contents
<Router history={ browserHistory } createElement={ createElement }>
<Route path='/' component={ require('../app') }>
<Route path='/about' component={ require('../about') } />
<Route />
<Router />
```

Updated Code

```
<Router history={ browserHistory } createElement={ createElement }>
<Route path='/' component={ require('../app') }>
  <IndexRoute component={ require('../home') } />
  <Route path="/about" component={ require('../about') } />
<Route />
<Router />
```

Comment: remove <Route />, third line. You closed this tag on previous line

Comment: Sorry I left out one line when copying, I have updated the question with the updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
<Router history={ browserHistory } createElement={ createElement }>
  <Route path='/' component={ require('../app') } />
  <Route path='/about' component={ require('../about') } />
<Router />
```

Comment: I came across IndexPath while doing research and wanted to use that, I updated my code, but I still get the same error.

Comment: maybe problem with includes `require('../app')`, can you make variable with this require, like App, About etc and write `<Route path='/' component={App} />`

Comment: I did that, and nothing changed, so I deleted all the routes inside the Router tag, and just had the Router tag, and I am still getting the error. So I am guessing the node server cannot read this syntax? But in my index.js I included `require('babel-register')({
  presets: ['react', 'es2015']
})`

Comment: try to add `{ presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1'] }`

Comment: Yes that got rid of the error. What does `stage-1` do?

Comment: i think it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37251552/whats-the-difference-between-babel-preset-stage-0-babel-preset-stage-1-etc

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your syntax is correct for your router

It should either be

```
<Router history={ browserHistory } createElement={ createElement }>
     <Route path='/' component={ require('../app') } />
     <Route path='/about' component={ require('../about') } />
<Router />
```

In the above case you had an empty route on third line and an unterminated route on first line which I have corrected.

or

```
<Router history={ browserHistory } createElement={ createElement }>
   <Route path='/' component={ require('../app') }>
       <Route path='/about' component={ require('../about') } />
    </Route>
<Router />
```

In above case route `/about` is a child of route `/` and hence when you close the route you need to have a syntax like `</Route>` and not `<Route/>`.

What I think is that you are looking for the second case and closed the `Route` incorrectly

Comment: I came across IndexPath while doing research and wanted to use that, I updated my code, but I still get the same error.