# What is a babel preset? What does stage mean?

Tags: babeljs

What is a **babel preset** and why do I need it?

There are several questions about specific babel presets but none explain the need for it (e.g. [what's the difference between babel-preset-stage-0, babel-preset-stage-1 etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37251552/whats-the-difference-between-babel-preset-stage-0-babel-preset-stage-1-etc))

Also the babel docs do not explain the necessity: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-latest/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Babel Presets:**

- **Technically** presets are **collections of plugins** (as Quentin says)
- The **usecase** is the **support of particular language features**.

Read this excellent post: https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/what-are-babel-plugins-and-presets

> A preset is a set of plugins used to **support particular language features**.
>
> The two presets Babel uses by **default**:
>
> - **es2015**: Adds support for ES2015 (or ES6) JavaScript
> - **react**: Adds support for JSX
>
> ... ES2015 is just another name used for ES6 ... [1]

**Preset stages:**

Stages represent the status of experimental features. Pre stage-3 should be used with caution.

> ... Beyond ES7, proposed JavaScript features can exist in various stages: [1]
>
> stage-0 - Strawman: just an idea, possible Babel plugin.
>
> stage-1 - Proposal: this is worth working on.
>
> stage-2 - Draft: initial spec.
>
> stage-3 - Candidate: complete spec and initial browser implementations.
>
> stage-4 - Finished: will be added to the next yearly release. [2]

[1] https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/what-are-babel-plugins-and-presets

[2] https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/

Answer (score 11):

From [the docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/):

> Presets are sharable .babelrc configs or simply an array of babel plugins.

Babel is a tool for transforming JS.

A plugin a some code for performing a particular transformation.

You have to specify which plugins you want to use with a config.

A preset is just a prewritten config you can use to get common sets of transforms.