# Arrow functions not compiling

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, arrow-functions, reactjs.net

I've been using Reactjs.net with Visual Studio and it compiles .jsx files that contain class methods defined using arrow functions syntax...

```
class A {

   m = () => {
   }
}
```

I've set up Webpack with ES2017 preset but it's giving an "unexpected token" error for the equals sign after the method name.

Why doesn't this compile?

Here is the loader section from my config...

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2017', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: I'm curious about this too. Never gotten it to work myself. `m: () =>` should work. Have you tried the `es2018` preset? Is that even a thing?

Comment: I think it's because I'm missing a 'stage'. What is a stage?

Comment: Did you actually downloaded and installed the preset?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it errors on missing preset.

Comment: [Babel Transform Class Properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/

And added 'stage-2' to the list of presets.

I worked out this solution after turning on and off the presets here with some sample code...

https://babeljs.io/repl

Comment: Bingo. In case you're still wondering what a stage is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37251552/whats-the-difference-between-babel-preset-stage-0-babel-preset-stage-1-etc